# Hide certain fields in Django admin site for different user

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have an admin site that I need to open up to more admins.

Currently my model looks like

```
class YouTube(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    credit_card_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Is there a way in the admin site frame work to make it so that only superusers can see the credit card number?  In the admin site framework, I can only see the ability to add, edit, delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create method **YouTube.get_cc_root_only**, where you are to check if user is root, and use it in YouTubeAdmin class (**list_display**)

**UPDATED:**

```
class XyzAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_cc_root_only(self, obj):
        if self.username == "admin":
            return "CC"
        return "XXX"

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context = None):
        self.username = request.user.username
        return super(XyzAdmin,self).changelist_view(request, extra_context = extra_context)

    list_display = ("name", "get_cc_root_only")
```

Comment: how can I check if user is root in `get_cc_root_only` method?

Comment: I want to see if the person who is viewing the admin site is a superuser.  How can I get that information from `get_cc_root_only(self)`

Comment: I modified my post, to get extra parameters for list

Comment: wow.  that is a very clever solution.  I learned some stuff along the way.  Thanks very much!

Comment: You are welcome :) But try to look at generic classes. I was not very happy studying them, but now I like them :)